# Error using cd- Cannot cd to Desktop?

Tags: matlab, cd

I have the following problem. The folder I am working in is ('Users/Desktop/data'). This is also what I get when I type pwd in Matlab. However, when i only copy that path and use cd('Users/Desktop/data') Matlab tells me that this is not a directory??
I have two versions of Matlab installed. Could that cause the error?

Best Laurie

Comment: What **exactly** do you see when you type `pwd`?

Comment: Usually a specific username user directory exists between Users and Desktop, i.e., `'Users/your_user_id/Desktop/data'`. There's also the shortcut to the current user's directory: `'~/Desktop/data'`.

Comment: I get 'Users/Desktop/data' . Thanks for your answers

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am using OS X Eel Capitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might be happening is that Matlab cannot find a directory  'Users/Desktop/data' nested under the one you are already in. You already are in 'User/Desktop/data' which does not have a "User" subfolder/subdirectory

What you need to do is to indicate the position of the directory you want to move in from the root '/'(Linux/MacOS) or from "C:"(Windows).

Either try 
`cd ..` to go in parent folder Desktop,
or `cd /.../User/Desktop/data`
(`C:\...\User\Desktop\data` in Windows)